# "Error: Member not found: 'JSON'", when trying to write Firebase Cloud Functions in Dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I already have Firebase Cloud Functions in JavaScript for an app. But I'm trying to arrange it so that I can write them in Dart, which will be automatically converted into JavaScript, following this instruction: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_functions_interop/latest/

When I come to the point of:

```
dart run build_runner build --output=build
```

(yes, I changed "pub" to "dart", since "pub" wasn't a defined operable or command, and "dart pub" etc was deprecated, according to the response I got... Could this be the root of the problem?),

I get this error:

```
Building package executable...
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/front_end-0.1.4+2/lib/src/fasta/crash.dart:96:45: Error: Member not found: 'JSON'.
        ..headers.contentType = ContentType.JSON
                                            ^^^^
```

and no `index.dart.js` file is created.

This is what my pubspec.yaml looks like:

```
name: functions
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev <3.0.0'
#  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
#  sdk: '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  firebase_functions_interop: 1.0.0
#  firebase_functions_interop: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: 1.0.0
#  build_runner: ^1.9.9
#  build_runner: ^2.0.3
#  build_runner: ^1.9.0
  build_node_compilers: 0.2.0
#  build_node_compilers: ^0.3.1
```

I have tried to upgrade everything, but since `build_node_compilers` seems to be quite an abandonded package (last update was 23 months ago), I can't use the latest version of `build_runner`...

I've done a number of flutter clean, flutter pub get (turned out to be a bad idea, since this is a Dart project), dart pub get, dart pub upgrade, dart pub upgrade --major-versions, firebase @latest etc... but this error won't go away.

Please help! I don't know where to even start looking...

Comment: This library seems to be abandoned (https://github.com/pulyaevskiy/firebase-functions-interop). I would consider looking at writing a dart file directly to deploy to cloudrun and using eventarc (https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/eventarc.v1/eventarc.v1-library.html) to listen to the events you want to subscribe to or act upon. This will probably be an easier on ramp than getting the build_runner to work. Build runner looks to be built upon deprecated dart2js technology whereas the new command is `dart compile js`.

Comment: Ok... but I have no idea how to do any of that!  Would you mind writing an answer and explain the steps involved? I would be most grateful!

Comment: I am not sure I will have the time to do a full write up on it. Have you taken a look at this existing guide : https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/server/google_apis ? This handles basic http requests from a http endpoint which may be what you are looking for. The event arc guide is a little more involved and involves listening to database events. I have yet to write a function that does that, but I am hoping that I can get around to testing that functionality out soon. Sorry I cannot be of more help right now.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you've noticed that there's a 50 point bounty on this qn, if you should find the time...  But in any case, I'll look into the resources you've recommended! Maybe it'll help.